# Get global form errors from the FormView in twig template

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

For rendering form errors in a twig template, you just have to use the `form_errors` twig macro without difference if it is a global form error or a field error.

But in my case, a global error is not rendered like a field error, so I can't use the `form_errors` twig macro for the two cases. I decide to use the macro for the field error & I would like to get the global form errors from the `Symfony\Component\Form\FormView` object. The goal is to iterate the global errors in the twig template & render them like I want.

Actually, I don't find any ressources on the symfony2 documentation which can help me.

Comment: Please post your edit as an answer and accept it, so that people having the same issue can see what solved it :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution by myself. For the people who want to do the same thing, the solution is to call `$formView->get("errors")` which gives you an array of `FormError`

Answer (score 3):

I'm using symfony 2.5 and it worked perfect for me in this way.

MyController

```
$error = new FormError(ErrorMessages::USER_NOT_AUTHENTICATED);
$form->addError($error);
```

MyView

```
{% for error in form.vars.errors %}
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    {{ error.messageTemplate|trans(error.messageParameters, 'validators')~'' }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

hope this will save someones time.

Answer (score 2):

in symfony 2.3 all accessor methods have been removed in favor of public properties to increase performance.

```
$formView->get("errors");
```

is now:

```
$formView->vars["errors"];
```

Visit [UPGRADE-2.1.md](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.1.md#deprecations) and refer to section "Deprecations" for more information.